# How to make a function to manage working hours

Tags: android, kotlin

I used Preference-Tree to set the value .
Here is my code

```kotlin
fun getWorkingHours(): Map<String, String> {
    val branches = libraryBranchesLiveData.value!!
    val hoursByDay : MutableMap<String, String> = mutableMapOf()
    val daysOfWeek = listOf("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat")

    if (branches[selectedBranchIdPositionInList].opened_time?.isEmpty() == true) {
        for (day in daysOfWeek) {
            hoursByDay[day] = "Closed"
        }
        return hoursByDay
    }

    for (day in daysOfWeek) {
        val hoursForDay = StringBuilder()
        var startHour : String? = ""

        for (workingHour in branches[selectedBranchIdPositionInList].opened_time!!) {
            Log.e("working hours: ", "workingHour:${workingHour}")
            val parts = workingHour!!.split(":", limit = 2)
            val dayRange = parts[0]
            val hours = parts[1]

            Log.e("working hours: ", "dayRange${dayRange}")
            Log.e("working hours: ", "hours${hours}")

            if (day in dayRange) {
                if (hoursForDay.isNotEmpty()) {
                    hoursForDay.append(", ")
                }
                hoursForDay.append(hours)
            }
        }

        if (hoursForDay.isNotEmpty()) {
            hoursByDay[day] = "$hoursForDay"
        } else {
            hoursByDay[day] = "Closed"
        }

        Log.e("working hours: ", "${hoursByDay}")
    }

    return hoursByDay
}
```

and here to call it and set the value

```
findPreference<Preference>(getString(R.string.branch_info_monday_opening_time_preference_key))?.summary = branchDetailsViewModel.getWorkingHours()["Mon"]
```

But it give this function is wrong the output of this function is

If the `"opened_time": ["Sun - Thu:8:00 am-8:00 pm","Fri:8:00 am-12:00 pm"]`, then:

```
Sun = 8:00 am-8:00 pm
Mon = Closed
Tue = Closed
Wed = Closed
Thu = 8:00 am-8:00 pm
Fri = 8:00 am-12:00 pm
```

I need to make a function which separate the date and time from an array which i get from api, like `"opened_time": ["Sun - Thu:8:00 am-8:00 pm","Fri:8:00 am-12:00 pm"]`. How I want to make a function to set it on behave of DayofWeek like this:

```
Sun = 8:00 am-8:00 pm
Mon = 8:00 am-8:00 pm
Tue = 8:00 am-8:00 pm
Wed = 8:00 am-8:00 pm
Thu = 8:00 am-8:00 pm
Fri = 8:00 am-12:00 pm
// and Saturday it will be like this
Sat = Closed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val parts = workingHour!!.split(":", limit = 2)
val dayRange = parts[0]

if (day in dayRange) {
    hoursForDay.append(hours)
}
```

You're not actually checking any range, you're just checking if the string `day` is present in the string `dayRange`. *Monday* is in the range *Sunday to Thursday*, but `"Mon"` isn't present in the text `"Sun - Thu"`. You need some logic to actually parse that as a range of days, and then check if your target day falls within it.

That's a little tricky since the ranges are circular. One quick way to do it is something like this:

```
// Get the day strings
val (startDay, endDay) = dayRange.split(" - ")
// Get their indices in the days list
val (start, end, target) = listOf(startDay, endDay, day).map {
    daysOfWeek.indexOf(it)
}

// Check if the target day's index falls between the other two
// Because the ranges are circular, the end day might have a lower index, 
// in which case we need to check from 'start' to the end of the list,
// and from the beginning of the list to 'end'
val inRange = if (start < end) target in start..end
    else target >= start || target <= end
```

One thing you need to watch out for is the `-1` you get if `indexOf` can't find a match in the list, which would always make `target <= end` *true*. You could do it differently (like check `target in 0..start || target in end..daysOfWeek.lastIndex`) but ideally that would never happen, because you should be validating these strings earlier and only checking them here if they're in the list. You could always add a line like `assert(listOf(start, end, target).all { it > -1 })` to make it clear that this function expects it to be handled, and that it's something that *needs* to be handled